# Standard Italian pronunciation of conjugated verbs

Tags: pronunciation

When I studied Italian for a few months in the U.S., with a native speaker, the difference in pronunciation between open and closed *e*’s and *o*’s received little attention, apart from distinguishing *e*=*and* from *è*=*is*. (Perhaps she spoke a dialect in which the differences are less than in Standard Italian.)

As I’ve continued with self-study, I’ve relied on a Collins Italian-American dictionary app to tell me whether a stressed *e* or *o* in a word should be open or closed, by looking at the IPA phonetic spelling of the word.

But for a verb, this only tells me how to pronounce the infinitive. The app’s conjugation tables don’t have phonetic spellings. (You can have the app speak them, but this gets tedious.)

When I read English Wikipedia’s article “[Italian phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_phonology)”, I discovered, for example, that in Standard Italian the *e* in *era* should be open but the *e*’s in *facesse* should be closed.

Is there an authoritative source that has phonetic pronunciations in Standard Italian for conjugations, or at least for verb endings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The** standard reference on Italian pronunciation is the [*Dizionario d’ortografia e di pronunzia*](https://www.dizionario.rai.it/), once a printed book and now in a web version with audio files added. It was originally compiled for RAI, the public broadcasting company, when a good, standard pronunciation was held in high esteem.

Unfortunately it uses a non-standard (but easily understandable) phonetic alphabet, explained starting [here](https://www.dizionario.rai.it/p.aspx?nID=trascrizioni-fonetiche).

In particular, what you seek about regular word endings is here: [“Desinenze grammaticali”](https://www.dizionario.rai.it/p.aspx?nID=desinenze-grammaticali) and pages following it.